# Product of cyclic groups is cyclic iff their orders are coprime

Tags: proof-verification

Let $G=(g^i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}},\ H=(h^i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ be finite cyclic groups such that $(g,h)$ generates $G\times H$. I want to prove that $\gcd(|g|,|h|)=1$ (where $|g|=|G|$,etc)

Let $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $(g,h)^k=(g,h^2)$. Then, 
$$k=1\mod|g|,\quad k=2\mod|h|$$
So, we can take $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $k=1+\alpha|g|=2+\beta|h|$. From this we get $\alpha|g|-\beta|h|=1$ and, then, by Bezout's lemma, we finally deduce that $|g|$ and $|h|$ are coprime.

Is this correct? A Yes or No is enough

Comment: You haven't said anything about the right to left direction.

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2546438/proof-of-prod-limitsi-1ng-i-is-cyclic-iff-gcd-operatornameord-g-i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a perfect proof.

However, it took me some time to parse the formula of your very idea: how did that exponent $2$ appear, shouldn't it be $k$, what happens to $g$, etc. So, some preliminary words could help the reader (perhaps only an "in particular").

Alternatively, you could e.g. choose a $k$ such that $(g,h)^k=(1,h)$ to get the same conclusion.

Comment: Thanks for your comments!